# how can i restore a wordpress site by mysql file only?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, backup, restore

I had a wordpress Site that it's down now , I have only mysql file . I want to restore my wordpress site with this file and i have not any more files to restore my old site, how can i do it ?

Comment: you cannot. even if you get the data for the website from the sql but how will you get the php pages as you dont have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if the following points are maintained :

1. Active Theme code should not be changed.
2. All the Plugins from previous installation need to be present in **wp-content/plugins** folder in new
3. Restore Mysql file into new database, and changed the db name in **wp-config.php**

Hope that will do.